# adding icon to link button in PHP/HTML/CSS - Adding an Icon to a button

Tags: php, html, css

i'm trying to add icon to this button

```
 <a href="<?= $gr[0]->gg_link ?>" class="btn btn-primary linkbtn" target="_blank" style="font-size : 20px; width:200px; height:40px;" >  click here to join </a>
```

i try this and did not work

```
<img class="img-center" src="<?= base_url() ?>/asset/other/appsicons/<?= $groups[0]->icon_name ?>"
```

Comment: Yuo're missing the closing `>` of the `<img` tag.

Comment: When you say you tried that, do you mean that you just put that `<img>` between the `<a>` tags? If you inspect the page, is the URL correct?

Comment: The end should be `?>">`

Comment: @Barmar I thought that might have been just a copy/paste mistake when they were writing the question, but maybe not.